# how to set css content property as dynamic value from table row

Tags: html, css

how to set css content property as dynamic value of table row and first child value?

my table html:

```
<table class="cTable">
    <tr> <td> CollegeName1 </td>.....</tr>
    <tr> <td> CollegeName2 </td>.....</tr>
    <tr> <td> CollegeName3 </td>.....</tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.cTable td:nth-of-type(1):before {
   content: "Institute Name";
}
```

Comment: Can you show the intended result as HTML, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `attr` expression.

```css
.cTable td:nth-of-type(1):before {
   content: attr(data-name);
}
```

```html
<table class="cTable">
    <tr> <td data-name="Institute Name 1"> CollegeName1 </td></tr>
    <tr> <td data-name="Institute Name 2"> CollegeName2 </td></tr>
    <tr> <td data-name="Institute Name 3"> CollegeName3 </td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use css variabels:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

```css
.cTable td:nth-of-type(1):before {
   content: var(--dinamic);
}
```

```html
<table class="cTable">
    <tr> <td style="--dinamic:'dinamic text1'"> CollegeName1 </td>.....</tr>
    <tr> <td style="--dinamic:'dinamic text2'"> CollegeName2 </td>.....</tr>
    <tr> <td style="--dinamic:'dinamic text3'"> CollegeName3 </td>.....</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tell me for help

Comment: CSS variable only work in modern  browser and this not valid use case